# Check if string contains any elements from list

Tags: python, list, contain

**Check Below for better explaination**
I have a long list of items in a file thats read line by line, and i want to sort all out that has a specific string in it. If the word does not contain any of the elements in sort, then it will be added to a dictionary. How do i do that? I have read some other situations on this website, but i just don't get it... So this might be a duplicate, but i need someone to explain me how to do this.
(Yes the items is from the game TF2)

```
item_list = ("Non-Tradable Ubersaw", "Screamin' Eagle", "'Non-Craftable Spy-cicle"

sort = ("Non-Tradable", "Non-Craftable") # The items that are not allowed
for word in item_list:
    if not sort in word:
        if word in items: # add to the dictionary
            items[word] += 1
        else:
            items[word] = 1
```

Already got it answered, but just to make the question clear.
I want to run sort the list: *item_list* and i wanted to do that by making a array: *sort* so it checks each element in *item_list* and check if the element have any of the elements from *sort* in it. If it didn't it added the element to a dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> item_list = ["Non-Tradable Ubersaw", "Screamin' Eagle", "'Non-Craftable Spy-cicle"]
>>> not_allowed = {"Non-Tradable", "Non-Craftable"}
```

You can use a list comprehension with `any` to check if any of the disallowed substrings are in the current element

```
>>> filtered = [i for i in item_list if not any(stop in i for stop in not_allowed)]
>>> filtered
["Screamin' Eagle"]
```

Comment: why make not_allowed a set?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Because all elements are unique (there is no point in checking twice if a duplicate is there) and the `in` operation is faster for `set` than `list` if the number of items gets large.

Comment: but you are not using in you are iterating over the set? If the OP creates the filter items there won't be dups

Comment: @PadraicCunningham .... oh. See what happens when I type before drinking my coffee? Yeah you're right, in this case it doesn't matter, it could be a `list`, `set`, or `tuple`.

Comment: @Cyber, could be worse, I cannot make a coffee as I have sciatica and have temporarily lost the use of my legs!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check each item in sort is not in each word  not compare the tuple to each word which is what `if not sort in word` is doing :

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = defaultdict(int)
for word in item_list:
    if not any(ele in  word for ele in srt):
        items[word] += 1
```

Worth adding as it actually answers the question as asked. As @JonClements suggests simply use a  Counter dict:

```
from collections import Counter
items = Counter(item for item in item_list if not any(word in item for word in sort))
```

using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) removes the need to check `if word in items`.

Comment: Why not: `items = Counter(item for item in item_list if not any(word in item for word in sort))` ?

Comment: @JonClements, i was just going to do something like that but based on the fact the OP's accepted answer the question now makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using python, but if the file is *really* huge, a good optimization would be to use some lower level commands, for example bash. Just as simple as this one-liner:

```
$ grep "text you are searching" my_file.txt | sort
```

Of course this bash code could be executed from python if needed, using the `subprocess` module.

Again, this is only worth if the file is huge and performance optimization matters. The bash commands will do the job way faster than a simple python loop.

I hope it helps.